# Need Help in understanding AWK script logic

Tags: shell, awk

I need help in understanding the below code logic written in AWK by one of our collegues in the past.
Can anyone with good AWK knowledge help me to understand this code.

Thanks,
Sandeep

```
sed -i 's/\r//g' $1 $2
sed -i 's/,/;/g' $1 $2
awk -F"|" '{if(FILENAME=="Parameter.txt"){a[$1]=NR;aa[NR]=$1;d=NR;if(NR==1){e=$1}else{e=e","$1};}
                        else if(FILENAME=="Traffic.csv"){h[FNR","$2]=$3;x[FNR","$4]=$5;k[FNR","$2","$3","$4","$5]=$1;y=FNR;}
                        else if(FILENAME=="Filter.txt"){for(i=1;i<=NF;i=i+3){if($(i+1)!="ne"){FE[FNR","$i]=$(i+2)}else{FNE[FNR","$i]=$(i+2)}};FILTER=FNR;FC[FNR]=(NF/3);}
                        else{
                                if(g==""){print e",TRAFFIC_CASE";g=1};
                                for(i=1;i<=d;i++){c[i]=""};l="";m="";z="";FINAL="";for(j=1;j<=FILTER;j++){FI[j]=""};
                                for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
                                                                        split($i,b,"=");
                                                                        if(a[b[1]]!=""){c[a[b[1]]]=b[2];};
                                                                        for(j=1;j<=y;j++){
                                                                                if(h[j","a[b[1]]]==b[2] && h[j","a[b[1]]]!=""){l=a[b[1]]","b[2]};
                                                                                if(x[j","a[b[1]]]==b[2] && x[j","a[b[1]]]!=""){z=a[b[1]]","b[2]};
                                                                                if(k[j","l","z]!=""){m=k[j","l","z]};};
                                                                        };
                                if(substr(FILENAME,20,3)=="SVC"){Q[c[a[MSISDN]]]=1}
                                else if(Q[c[a[MSISDN]]]!=1){
                                        for(i=1;i<=d;i++){
                                                                                if(i==1){f=c[1];}else{f=f","c[i]};
                                                                                if(c[i]==""){c[i]="B"};
                                                                                for(j=1;j<=FILTER;j++){
                                                                                        if(FE[j","i]!=""){if(FE[j","i]==c[i] && (FI[j]=="" || FI[j]<=FC[j])){FI[j]=FI[j]+1;}else{FI[j]=FI[j]-1;}};
                                                                                        if(FNE[j","i]!=""){if(FNE[j","i]!=c[i] && (FI[j]=="" || FI[j]<=FC[j])){FI[j]=FI[j]+1;}else{FI[j]=FI[j]-1;}};
                                                                                        };
                                                                                };
                                                                        }
                                for(j=1;j<=FILTER;j++){if(FI[j]==FC[j]){FINAL=1};};
                                if(FINAL!=1){print f","m;};
                                };
                        }' Parameter.txt Traffic.csv Filter.txt $2 $1
```

Comment: Run `gawk -o- ` on the awk script (see the man page) to pretty-print it. You'll understand it MUCH better once it's read-ably formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code pretty-printed by `gawk -o` to make it readable (in case you don't have gawk) so you can hopefully figure it out for yourself:

```
{
    if (FILENAME == "Parameter.txt") {
        a[$1] = NR
        aa[NR] = $1
        d = NR
        if (NR == 1) {
            e = $1
        } else {
            e = e "," $1
        }
    } else if (FILENAME == "Traffic.csv") {
        h[FNR "," $2] = $3
        x[FNR "," $4] = $5
        k[FNR "," $2 "," $3 "," $4 "," $5] = $1
        y = FNR
    } else if (FILENAME == "Filter.txt") {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i = i + 3) {
            if ($(i + 1) != "ne") {
                FE[FNR "," $i] = $(i + 2)
            } else {
                FNE[FNR "," $i] = $(i + 2)
            }
        }
        FILTER = FNR
        FC[FNR] = (NF / 3)
    } else {
        if (g == "") {
            print e ",TRAFFIC_CASE"
            g = 1
        }
        for (i = 1; i <= d; i++) {
            c[i] = ""
        }
        l = ""
        m = ""
        z = ""
        FINAL = ""
        for (j = 1; j <= FILTER; j++) {
            FI[j] = ""
        }
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
            split($i, b, "=")
            if (a[b[1]] != "") {
                c[a[b[1]]] = b[2]
            }
            for (j = 1; j <= y; j++) {
                if (h[j "," a[b[1]]] == b[2] && h[j "," a[b[1]]] != "") {
                    l = a[b[1]] "," b[2]
                }
                if (x[j "," a[b[1]]] == b[2] && x[j "," a[b[1]]] != "") {
                    z = a[b[1]] "," b[2]
                }
                if (k[j "," l "," z] != "") {
                    m = k[j "," l "," z]
                }
            }
        }
        if (substr(FILENAME, 20, 3) == "SVC") {
            Q[c[a[MSISDN]]] = 1
        } else if (Q[c[a[MSISDN]]] != 1) {
            for (i = 1; i <= d; i++) {
                if (i == 1) {
                    f = c[1]
                } else {
                    f = f "," c[i]
                }
                if (c[i] == "") {
                    c[i] = "B"
                }
                for (j = 1; j <= FILTER; j++) {
                    if (FE[j "," i] != "") {
                        if (FE[j "," i] == c[i] && (FI[j] == "" || FI[j] <= FC[j])) {
                            FI[j] = FI[j] + 1
                        } else {
                            FI[j] = FI[j] - 1
                        }
                    }
                    if (FNE[j "," i] != "") {
                        if (FNE[j "," i] != c[i] && (FI[j] == "" || FI[j] <= FC[j])) {
                            FI[j] = FI[j] + 1
                        } else {
                            FI[j] = FI[j] - 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (j = 1; j <= FILTER; j++) {
            if (FI[j] == FC[j]) {
                FINAL = 1
            }
        }
        if (FINAL != 1) {
            print f "," m
        }
    }
}
```

Now that it's formatted legibly step 2 for you in trying to understand the script is to rename all of the variables to be whatever it is they truly represent, e.g. `a[$1]=NR` -> `param2lineNr[$1]=NR` and `aa[NR]=$1` -> `lineNr2param[NR]=$1` or similar depending on what `$1` is in that `Parameter.txt` file. You should also introduce some intermediate well-named variables so you're not trying to figure out what constructs like `Q[c[a[MSISDN]]]` actually mean next time you read the code (that looks very much like a bug to me btw as `MSISDN` is an uninitialized variable - the author probably meant `Q[c[a["MSISDN"]]]` but idk for sure). Once you've managed to do that for all variables the meaning of the script as a whole should be clear. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks ..But how did you executed the gawk -o over this file: I tried the same and got the below o/p


`[root@meylvvmnmt01 /tmp/script]# gawk -o Pre_CDR_1.sh
Usage: gawk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
Usage: gawk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...
POSIX options:          GNU long options: (standard)`

Comment: Look up the man page and/or run `gawk --help`, it's not hard to figure out. Also I'm guessing that `Pre_CDR_1.sh` is your **shell** script not the **awk** script stored within it. You're going to want to run gawk on your awk script, not your shell script.

Answer (score 0):

We have the parameters, traffic cases and filters in files... this is a big enough script that it also wants to be in a stand-alone file.

My process:

1. I reformatted and dropped the result in vim
2. I eliminated one nest by pattern matching outside the first set of brackets.
3. I saw the concatenation of `","` in arrays... can use SUBSEP for this (after some further refactoring, can probably eliminate the SUBSEP definition... it's not relevant
4. Those places I saw a check for `if (foo[bar] == "")`, I replaced that for the more intuitive `if (bar in foo)`
5. I started replacing with `s/\<x\>/something_x/g` -- vim is really nice for this because you can isolate variable names using `\<` `\>`...
6. I replaced blanking arrays with `split("", arr)`
7. I saw the b[1] was a key and b[2] was a value... best to create intermediate variables to make the traffic match section more readable.
8. Going through each variable started revealing unused variables like `aa`.
9. I changed things like `foo = foo + 1` to `foo++`
10. I reversed logic conditions in `if` statements where it seemed appropriate and got rid of superfluous `{}`.
11. I did some refactoring around the filtering bit to reduce the number of array lookups.

Here's my guess:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = "|"
    fileno = 0
    SUBSEP = ","
}

FILENAME == "Parameter.txt" {
    param[$1] = NR
    param_sz = NR
    if (FNR == 1)
        param_list = $1
    else
        param_list = param_list "," $1
    next
}

FILENAME == "Traffic.csv" {
    traffic_h[FNR, $2] = $3
    traffic_x[FNR, $4] = $5
    traffic_key[FNR, $2, $3, $4, $5] = $1
    traffic_sz = FNR
    next
}

FILENAME == "Filter.txt" {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 3) {
        if ($(i + 1) == "ne")
            filter_ne[FNR, $i] = $(i + 2)
        else
            filter_eq[FNR, $i] = $(i + 2)
    }
    filter_sz = FNR
    filters[FNR] = (NF / 3)
    next
}

fileno == 0  {
    print param_list ",TRAFFIC_CASE"
    fileno = FNR
}

{
    split("", case)
    l = ""
    traffic_match = ""
    z = ""
    final_filter = 0
    split("", filtered)

    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        split($i, b, "=")
        key = b[1]
        val = b[2]
        if (key in param) {
            this_param = param[key]
            case[this_param] = val
            for (t = 1; t <= traffic_sz; t++) {
                if ((t, this_param == val && traffic_h[t, this_param]) in traffic_h)
                    l = val
                if ((t, this_param == val && traffic_x[j, this_param]) in traffic_x)
                    z = val
                if ((t, this_param, l, this_param, z) in traffic_key)
                    traffic_match = traffic_key[t, this_param, l, this_param, z]
            }
        }
    }
    if (substr(FILENAME, 20, 3) == "SVC") {
        svc_case[case[param["MSISDN"]]] = "" # << MSISDN was = "" so... arbitrary string should be OK or... should fix your bug?
    }
    if (!(case[param["MSISDN"]] in svc_case)) {
        for (p = 1; p <= param_sz; p++) {
            if (p == 1)
                case_list = case[1]
            else
                case_list = case_list "," case[i]
            if (!(p in case))
                case[p] = "B"
            for (f = 1; f <= filter_sz; f++) {
                if ((f, p) in filter_eq) {
                    if (filter_eq[f, p] == case[p] && (!f in filtered) || filtered[f] <= filters[f]))
                        ++filtered[f]
                    else
                        --filtered[f]
                } else if ((j, i) in filter_ne) {
                    if (filter_ne[f, p] != case[p] && (!(f in filtered) || filtered[f] <= filters[f]))
                        ++filtered[f]
                    else
                        --filtered[f]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (f = 1; f <= filter_sz; f++)
        if (filtered[f] == filters[f])
            final_filter = 1
    if (!final_filter)
        print case_list "," traffic_match
}
```

So, it's very, very likely I got something wrong because I have no I/O to work with for a test-case -- but you can repeat my steps to figure out reality.  I'd work through that filtering piece a bit more... I'd check "MSISDN" (like Ed suggested) and see if that looks interesting to you...

Another thing that looks suspect is that you are ostensibly trying to parse a .csv file with "|" as a delimiter... that's probably not going to work.